# PowerShell splatting SecureString is converted to String

Tags: powershell

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [securestring]
    $securityKey
)

powershell.exe -File $PSCommandPath -thisAppDomain @PSBoundParameters
```

This code throws the following error:

> Cannot process argument transformation on
>   parameter 'securityKey'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString"

If I check the type of `securityKey`, its is a SecureString before its splatted. I assume its serializing it for some reason. How do I prevent this?

### Edit

This use case may look strange so Ill provide some context. I need to ensure a specific version of an assembly is loaded when piping into this script. I'm using the `thisAppDomain` param to relaunch in a new app domain to attempt to accomplish this. Larger example:

```
.\FirstScript.ps1 | .\SecondScript.ps1
```

The secure string is piping in as expected, but is converted to a string when relaunching. This is how I relaunch:

```
if(-not $thisAppDomain)
{
    Write-Host "Invoking script in a new app domain"
    powershell.exe -File $PSCommandPath -thisAppDomain @PSBoundParameters
    return;
}
```

Comment: How do you call this script? Can you show an example? Mostly trying to see what `-thisAppDomain` might be expecting. What is your powerShell version

Comment: powershell.exe is not a powershell cmdlet, so I don't see how splatting could work.  It's a command-line program and only takes string inputs on the command-line.

Comment: If you wanted to splat to the command, you could try: & $PSCommandPath -thisAppDomain @PSBoundParameters  (to avoid going out to a new powershell.exe)

Comment: Added more detail.

Comment: your code is not a fully functioning, working, minimal example, so hard to repro and test an idea.  convert the securestring to base64 encoded string/structure, pass that into the 2nd and convert back.  may need c# code in the script...don't know...have not tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **call PowerShell's CLI with `-File`, all arguments are invariably converted to *strings***, so your secure string won't work (it is converted to a regular string with *literal* contents `System.Security.SecureString`).

**In order to (mostly) preserve argument types, you must pass a *script block***, which causes PowerShell to automatically serialize and deserialize arguments in a type-preserving way<sup>[1]</sup>, which preserves `[securestring]` instances correctly, but note that this technique only works when calling *from* PowerShell (too):

```
if (-not $thisAppDomain)
{
  Write-Host "Invoking script in a new app domain"
  powershell -Command { 
      $script, $splat = $Args # parse the args array into distinct variables
      . $script -thisAppDomain @splat # call the script with splatting
    } -args $PSCommandPath, $PSBoundParameters
  return
}
```

Note how the values from the caller's context that must be referenced in the script block - which will be executed in the *new* session - must be passed *as arguments*, via `-args <arg-array>` - see [`Get-Help about_powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) or run `powershell -?` for more concise help.

**Note**: As  [Patrick Meinecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930135/patrick-meinecke) points out, the above approach, which uses a transformed command line with a Base64-encoded string behind the scenes, can hypothetically fail due to exceeding the max. command-line length, which is 32,768 characters in Windows 10 (see the [`CreateProcess` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)).
That said, unless you pass exceptionally large script blocks and/or hundreds of arguments, you're unlikely to run into this limit.

---

<sup>[1] The same type of serialization is also used in PowerShell remoting and with background jobs, for instance. Note that not only a fixed set of types can be deserialized faithfully, but PowerShell does its best to *emulate* other types with *custom objects* that have the same properties.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Splatted arguments on an executable (even `powershell.exe`) are just converted to a string.  You can see how it would end up by running this:

```
$splat = @{ Test = 'something'; Secret = [securestring]::new() }
cmd.exe /c echo @splat
# returns
# -Test:something -Secret:System.Security.SecureString
```

You can run something in another process while using the `SecureString` by using `Start-Job`

```
$mySecureString = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$job = Start-Job {
    & $using:PSCommandPath -thisAppDomain $using:mySecureString
}

$job | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Note: the `using` scope must be used for variables from the parent session.  Also, variables will still be serialized since processes do not share memory, but the secure string will be serialized correctly.